# Entrypoint isn't within the current project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have updated my android studio to Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

after an update, it gives the error **Entrypoint isn't within the current project**. i have attached my project structure below.

[image]

Comment: Where is your `main` function defined?

Comment: Inside the lib directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same. This was one of many issues when I updated to Electric Eel from Dolphin.

In my case I right clicked the root folder in the project structure and clicked `Mark Directory as` `sources root`.

Comment: This one did it for me, very nice thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this steps (By doing this, I became)

1. Delete three directory (after android Studio exit)

   - `.android`,
   - `.ios`,
   - `.idea`
2. open android studio and wait
3. and invalidate caches

Comment: Thanks. I found just deleting `.idea` and restarting Android Studio (Iguana on Mac) was enough to fix it permanently